# How to use credential type "SSH Username with private key" inside jenkinsfile for pipeline job

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I'm trying to run remote commands using ssh from jenkinsfile. For this I'm using *.pem file for accessing the remote machine. I already have jenkins credentials created with the type "SSH Username with private key" inside jenkins.

Is there any way that i can use that credential inside jenkinsfile instead of giving sh "ssh -i *.pem username@hostname command" to authenticate?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, you would need to use `Jenkins Credentials Binding Plugin`. Basically you create a binding from the key file, set the key as any variable , lets say `mykey` and you can use the key in your build scripts as `cat mykey`. 
Or store in your build script as:

```
cat mykey > sshkey
chmod 600 sshkey
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add sshkey
```

and then you can ssh since the ssh key is added
This post lays all features of Jenkins Credentials Binding plugin really good https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/203802500-Injecting-Secrets-into-Jenkins-Build-Jobs

Comment: To elaborate, I believe you're saying to set the "Key File Variable" field to `mykey`. There isn't any reason to copy the key to `sshkey`, just `eval \`ssh-agent -s\`; ssh-add "$mykey"`. Use `"$mykey"` because it's an environment variable, quoted because it may contain spaces.